# Use join table column in split function in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

I have a split function which is working well in SQL.

Users table has a column `experience` which contains comma-separated string as values, like this

```
ID   |  Exp
---------------------------
1    | C#,WEBAPI,SQL
2    | ASP.Net,MVC,HTML,CSS
3    | HTML,CSS,JavaScript
```

I am trying something:

```
Select 
    U.ID, B.Text
From 
    Users U, 
    Split(U.Exp, ',') B
```

Because I need result like:

```
ID   |  Exp
---------------------------
1    | C#
1    | WEBAPI
1    | SQL
2    | ASP.Net
2    | MVC
2    | HTML
2    | CSS
3    | HTML
3    | CSS
3    | JavaScript
```

Any clue how to use the join table in function in join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `cross apply`:

```
Select U.ID, B.Text
From Users U cross apply
     dbo.Split(U.Exp, ',') B(Text);
```

If you want to keep all rows in `U` even if `U.Exp` is empty, then you would use `outer apply`.

Answer (score 1):

This should be something like this

```
Select U.ID, B.Text
From Users U
CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(U.Exp, ',') B
```

Btw: `OUTER APPLY` would join all of them in any case...

Comment: It is always giving error: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5    The multi-part identifier "U.Exp" could not be bound. I am already using the same query by using , in place of cross join (both are same)

Comment: Should this be `CROSS APPLY` instead?